# iOS store selection for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, selection

for example native iOS apps Mail and Notes:

1)if you select a cell - the app pushes view controller

2)if you click back button after step 1 - the app pops view controller and you see that this cell is selected and becomes deselected with animation

How to implement the same behaviour? Currently I need to add it to each table in my app.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: The only idea I have is to store the selected index manually and customize the cell when it appears according to this index. But it will be a hell to add this behaviour to each screen/cell manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a UITableView within a UIViewController (and not a UITableViewController, which has the behaviour you mention by default).

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is when you use a table with reusable cells - they are all recreated. So `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` will return nil for this code in most situations

Comment: You are right - cells are not recreated by themself. Thanks. But anyways `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` always return nil.

Comment: Are you calling deselectRow already somewhere else? (like in didSelectRow...)

Comment: I call `deselectRow...` in `didSelectRow...` only. And I tried both cases - with and without of this string of code - in both cases I get nil.

Comment: You should only ever be calling deselect in viewWillAppear. I've edited my code above to use viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear (and now edited it back).

Comment: You should use ViewDidAppear, since the goal is to mimic the default behaviour.

Comment: wait. It seems a bug of xCode/iOS - I tried again and now it works - returns index path instead of nil

Comment: @LastMove Yeah, I thought so as well. The property name of 'clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear' always throws me off since it contains 'viewWillAppear'.

Comment: Yes - you should fix your answer - it seems native apps' behaviour is implemented in `viewWillAppear` method (according to animation)

Answer (score 1):

Actually It the default behaviour of UITableViewController. 
If you are using UITableViewController just check this box in your storyboard : 
[image: clear on appearance]

If you are not using UITableViewController, in your viewDidAppear (so the user can see it, just unselect the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I didn't use `UITableViewController` and I hope to add the similar without of rewriting each view controller